# How to change the value of a key in a properties file loaded by the maven-surefire-plugin without having to manually edit the file?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using maven sure fire plugin to load the key-value pairs from a properties file (testdata.properties) so that i can use it in my TestNG test method like

```
@Test
public void testDBConnection()
{ 
    String dbEnvUsed = System.getProperty("db.env");
    String keyForDatabaseDriver = System.getProperty("db.driver");
    String keyForDatabaseUrl = System.getProperty("db."+dbEnvUsed+".url");// value of the key "db.tst.url"
    String keyForDatabaseUser = System.getProperty("db."+dbEnvUsed+".user";//value of the key "db.tst.user"
    String keyForDatabasePassword = System.getProperty("db."+dbEnvUsed+".passwd");//value of the key "db.tst.passwd"
    Connection conn = null;
    try
    {
       Class.forName(dbDriver); // load the database driver
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(keyForDatabaseUrl, keyForDatabaseUser, keyForDatabasePassword);
            System.out.println("----> Connected to " + dbEnvUsed +" instance");
    } 
    catch(java.sql.SQLRecoverableException sqlre)
    {
            System.out.println("----> Could not establish the connection. DB Server may be down.");
    }
    catch(Exception se)
    {
            System.out.println(se.getMessage());
    }
    Assert.assertNotNull(conn);//test the conection
}
```

contents of testdata.properties file

```
db.driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.env= tst

db.tst.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:sid
db.tst.user = tstUser
db.tst.passwd = *****

db.dev.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:sid
db.dev.user = devUser
db.dev.passwd = ######
```

Excerpt from my pom.xml

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <systemPropertiesFile>src/main/resources/testdata.properties</systemPropertiesFile>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I want to change the value of the key "db.env" before executing the test without having to edit the testdata.properties file. Is there any way to achieve the same ?

Comment: How exactly did you load the properties ? I'm surprised to see you looking up for them on `System`, I would have expected a simple `java.util.Properties` instance, which would allow you to save easily your updated properties by the way

Comment: maven-surefire-plugin takes care of that. If you specify the path of your properties file within the <systemPropertiesFile> (see Excerpt from my pom.xml), it would load them up and you can access them in your code via System.getProperty("your.key"). I have found this to be working.

Comment: BTW, i was accessing my properties earlier by creating an instance of java.util.Properties. I switched to using maven-surefire-plugin to way of loading properties as it saved coding a few lines, although it affects the readability of the code (for someone who is not familiar with this usage).

Comment: Well, I don't know this plugin but I guess that once your properties have been added to the system properties, you cannot distinguish the properties that were already here from those you added later. You can always use `Properties.save` on `System.getProperties` (optionally, you could filter the properties of the system : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Answer (score 1):

found that maven provides a way to override the value of the of key in your properties file. Below is one way of doing it:

```
mvn -D<key.to.override>=<yourvalue>
```

In my case, i did this:

```
mvn -Dtest= testDBConnection test -Ddb.env=tst
```

Note that i have a key "**db.env**" defined in the **testdata.properties** file which is loaded by the maven-surefire-plugin. So, the value of the key "db.env" can be accessed within my code by using `System.getProperty("db.env");`.

To make this (loading of your properties file in a way such that your key-value pair can be accessed by using `System.getProperty("key.in.your.property")`) happen, add the below in your pom.xml

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertiesFile>src/main/resources/testdata.properties</systemPropertiesFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```